# Firestore pricing for large/complex queries

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Before diving into the database for my mobile app, I want to make sure I have some pricing concerns cleared up.

I am creating a video based social network that will have an endless feed with content from other accounts posts. One feature of the app is that the user should never see the same video twice in this feed.

My plan was to have a collection of [Posts] that contain every post/video in order of date for the app and to get/read 15 or so of those until a user scrolls to a certain point, then get the next 15, and so on.

My main concern is, If I implement a query to get a limit(15) and some sort of test to make sure the user hasn't already seen that post, will I read every single one of the posts before returning?

For example, if I have 30k posts in the collection and I grabbed the first 15 that the user hasn't seen, will I be charged with 30k reads or 15 reads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only charged for documents returned by a query.  It doesn't matter how big the collection is.  If you ask for 15 documents, and you receive 15 documents, then you are charged for 15 document reads.