Read/Write operation count for pricing in Firestore query operations
In Firebase, if I have 100,000 (hundred thousand) documents in one collection, and if I query by something between them and if the result is 100 documents, how many read/write operations are counted for pricing here? 100 or 100,000? Can someone professional answer this?
Edit:
Some questions are claimed to be the same question. But the subjects in those questions are different with mine in stack overflow as you see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55889972/20742532 (question about performance)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46605575/20742532 (question about performance)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61493141/20742532 (similar question, but answer has just 1 reputation, which creates doubt whether the answer is correct or not)
Doug Stevenson's answer is about the performance issue, not the pricing issues. Therefore the similar questions don't reflect the answer that I need. The question is simple, and having also conflicted answers in stackoverflow. Therefore I tried to make it a simple question, for a simple answer.
